# Does time on a German fiktionsbescheinigung visa count against the 90/180 time limit?

Tags: schengen, germany, 90-180-visa-rules

I just returned to the U.S. from Germany after my work visa was rejected

I entered the Schengen zone on July 30th, 2018 and began looking for work out there casually. I received a job offer from a start-up and began applying for a work permit. In the meantime, as my Schengen time was nearly up, the ausländerbehörde gave me a fiktionsbescheinigung.

Later, this office rejected my request for a visa. I left the Schengen zone to the states on the 12th of December.

I am wondering how long I have to wait in order to return to the Schengen zone, so that I can begin to look for work out there again. I am looking for a company to support an EU-blue card and in my opinion it is best to look there rather than attempt to find a position from the states.

Comment: Afaict the question boils down to whether time on a "fiktionsbescheinigung" counts against the 90/180 limit or not. Time on a proper long term visa or residence permit does not but I dunnot what the rules surrounding the various types of country-specific temporary residence document are.

Comment: @PeterGreen that is correct.  It depends on whether box 3 on the third page was selected.  Joseph Schafer: was it?

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify.  Putting on hold.

Comment: If anyone wants more information about the 3 boxes https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/67622/applied-for-blue-card-in-germany-visa-expired-can-i-travel-back-to-my-country